# Image processing using MATLAB, matrices

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm currently working with MATLAB to do some image processing. I've been set a task to basically recreate the convolution function for applying filters. I managed to get the code working okay and everything seemed to be fine.

The next part was for me to do the following..

Write your own m-function for [unsharp masking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsharp_masking) of a given image to produce a new output image.

Your function should apply the following steps:

- Apply smoothing to produce a blurred version of the original image,
- Subtract the blurred image from the original image to produce an edge image,
- Add the edge image to the original image to produce a sharpened image.

Again I've got code mocked up to do this but I run into a few problems. When carrying out the convolution, my image is cropped down by one pixel, this means when I go to carry out the subtraction for the unsharpening the images are not the same size and the subtraction cannot take place.

To overcome this I want to create a blank matrix in the convolution function that is the same size as the image being inputted, the new image will then go on top of this matrix so in affect the new image has a one pixel border around it to make it to its original size. When I try and implement this, all I get as an output is the blank matrix I just created. Why is this happening and if so would you be able to help me fix it?

My code is as follows.

#### Convolution

```
function [ imgout ] = convolution( img, filter )
    %UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
    %   Detailed explanation goes here

    [height, width] = size(img);     % height, width: number of im rows, etc.
    [filter_height, filter_width] = size(filter);

    for height_bound = 1:height - filter_height + 1; % Loop over output elements
        for width_bound = 1:width - filter_width + 1;
            imgout = zeros(height_bound, width_bound); % Makes an empty matrix the correct size of the image.
            sum = 0;
            for fh = 1:filter_height    % Loop over mask elements
                for fw = 1:filter_width
                    sum = sum + img(height_bound - fh + filter_height, width_bound - fw + filter_width) * filter(fh, fw);
                end
            end

            imgout(height_bound, width_bound) = sum;  % Store the result
        end
    end

    imshow(imgout)
end
```

#### Unsharpen

```
function sharpen_image = img_sharpen(img)
    blur_image = medfilt2(img);
    convolution(img, filter);
    edge_image = img - blur_image;
    sharpen_image = img + edge_image;
end
```

Comment: You and him (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221114/convolution-m-function-in-matlab-without-using-built-in-tools) seem to be doing the same homework.

Comment: The result of the convolution doesn't necessarily have to be of a different size than the input.  You just have to handle the boundary artifacts correctly.

Comment: You really shouldn't change existing questions to something completely different.  Now the comments left for the old one don't make any sense.

Comment: Is this a Matlab or a C# question?

Comment: Take a couple days to read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Concatenation, e.g.:

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];  % Matrix
B = [7; 8];          % Column vector
C = [A B];           % Concatenate
```